# JWT authentication with gundb

Tags: gun

Can i use [JWT](https://jwt.io/#libraries) authentication with gundb? And if so, would it dramatically slow down my sync speed? I was going to try and implement a test using the tutorial [here](https://jwt.io/introduction/) but wanted to see if there were any 'gotchas' I should be aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API has changed to use a middleware system. The SEA (Security, Encryption, Authorization) framework will be published to handle stuff like this. However, you can roll your own by doing something like this on the server:

```
Gun.on('opt', function(ctx){
  if(ctx.once){ return }
  ctx.on('in', function(msg){
    var to = this.to;
    // process message.
    to.next(msg); // pass to next middleware
  });
});
```

Registering the `in` listener via the `opt` hook lets this middleware become 1st in line (before even gun core), that way you can filter all inputs and reject them if necessary (by not calling `to.next(msg)`).

Likewise to add headers on the client you would want to register an `out` listener (similarly to how we did for the `in`) and modify the outgoing message to have `msg.headers = {token: data}` and then pass it forward to the next middleware layers (which will probably be websocket/transport hooks) by doing `to.next(msg)` as well. More docs to come on this as it stabilizes.

### Old Answer:

A very late answer, sorry this was not addressed sooner:

The default websocket/ajax adapter allows you to update a `headers` property that gets passed on every networked message:

```
gun.opt({
  headers: { token: JWT },
});
```

On the server you can then intercept and reject/authorize requests based on the token:

```
gun.wsp(server, function(req, res, next){
    if('get' === req.method){
        return next(req, res);
    }
    if('put' === req.method){
        return res({body: {err: "Permission denied!"}});
    }
});
```

The above example rejects all writes and authorizes all reads, but you would replace this logic with your own rules.